# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel (works when running Fiddler)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, fiddler

I'm trying to send a send a webrequest to the url "https://boligsurf.dk".

However I keep getting the following error:

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

The strange thing is that when I try again with FIDDLER running the request works fine.

Does anyone know what could be the reason this exception is being thrown? 
I have looked at similar issues but couldn't find any solutions to my issue.

Feel free to try the URL on your own and see if you get the error too!

By the way I'm using the *System.Net.HttpWebRequest* class.

Comment: What client do you use? Which version? If it is IE8 than your problem is that this client does not support SNI.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich 
I'm using the System.Net.HttpWebRequest.

Comment: Hard to tell without code (i.e. minimal example to reproduce the problem) and maybe packet capture.  But it could be that you are using a version which [does not support SNI](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11487) yet  or that you are trying to use SSL 3.0.